# Space in batch file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to run a simple batch file.

```
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "%~dp0\EnsembleIndependant\*.mis"') DO (ECHO %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt & CALL vorace.exe -f %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt)
```

this only works if there is no space in the path of the batch file.

the batch is in:

C:\Users\Rafael\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\vorace\Release\vorace.exe

the files I want to loop through are in:

C:\Users\Rafael\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\vorace\Release\EnsembleIndependant

can anyone help me.

thanks.

thank you guys for the suggestions. 
for /f "delims=" solved my problem.

Comment: Where exactly is it failing? Try to quote the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s "%~dp0EnsembleIndependant\*.mis"') DO (ECHO %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt & CALL vorace.exe -f %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt)
```

`%~dp0` has already a backspace at the end.

Comment: The character is termed backslash.  I just commented here to say that Windows now doesn't care if two backslashes are in sequence, it treats them as one backslash.

Answer (score 3):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s "%~dp0\EnsembleIndependant\*.mis"') DO (ECHO %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt & CALL vorace.exe -f %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt)
```

space is a standard delimiter in batch for loops as well as `<tab>` and with `"delims="` you deactivate it.

Answer (score 2):

FOR /F uses as standard delimiters `space` and `tab`, to avoid this you need to add the options.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s "%~dp0\EnsembleIndependant\*.mis"') DO (ECHO %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt & CALL vorace.exe -f %%a >> ResultatVorace.txt)
```