# Parsing results of For /F with a space or period in the output

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I am trying to run a `For` loop to scan a directory and pass the output to a RoboCopy command. This works great for all the files except if they have a space path. As an example one of the directories will be \Win7_Images\1.Copy to USB\

This is my original code.

```
For /f %%b In ('Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"') Do (Robocopy %%b I:\Images *.wim /xo /r:1 /Log+:I:\Images\filecopy.log)
```

I've searched several posts that refer to spaces in for loops but can't seem to get this working use their suggestions.
Here is what I'm getting:

```
2014/12/12 11:56:02 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory \\ServerName\pc_images\Win7_Images\1\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As you can see, it's stopping at the period.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615784/space-in-batch-file-path) suggested using `delims=` so I tried the following

```
For /f "delims=" %%b In ('Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"') Do (Robocopy %%b i:\Images *.wim /xo /r:1)
```

This doesn't work either, I get the following:

Started : Fri Dec 12 12:25:38 2014

Source - \SERVER\pc_images\Win7_Images\1\
     Dest - H:\Projects\SA projects\Windows Imaging automation\Create\

```
Files : a
    Bootable
    USB
    Drive
```

The final piece of the puzzle here is that I really don't need this directory to be copied but I just don't want the error in the output. I have tried to exclude that directory this way:

`For /f %%b In ('Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"') Do (Robocopy %%b I:\Images *.wim /xo /xd "%FP_Sever%\PC_Images\Win7_images\1. Create a Bootable USB Drive" /r:1)`

and since the robocopy output indicated that everything was being dropped after the 1 I tried this

```
For /f %%b In ('Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"') Do (Robocopy %%b I:\Images *.wim /xo /xd "%FP_Sever%\PC_Images\Win7_images\1\ /r:1)
```

So my questions are 1. How do I get parse paths that have a period and/or space and why isn't that directory being ignored in the RoboCopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include quotes in your paths on an inline command, it's best to use the `usebackq` parameter in your `FOR` statement:

```
REM Updated parameters after the /f switch
REM  and changed the command to use ` instead of ' marks.
For /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%b In (`Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"`) Do (...)
```

Regarding your Robocopy command, make sure you quote the `%%b` parameter which is used in the `DO` command as it could contain spaces itself:

```
Robocopy "%%b" ...
```

Full command updated:

```
For /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%b In (`Dir /b /s /a:d "%fp_server%\pc_images\Win7_Images"`) Do (Robocopy "%%b" I:\Images *.wim /xo /xd "%FP_Sever%\PC_Images\Win7_images\1. Create a Bootable USB Drive" /r:1)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Jason this worked on both fronts. Fixed the error related to the path and excluded the directory in the RoboCopy command. I appreciate the help!